# Black Screen Macbook 10.1

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, login, macbook, gpu-driver

I have a lot of issues with my MBP10.1 and NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu 14.04.02LTS.

When I install them, i get a black screen after reboot.
I tried `nomodeset` (didn't work) and `gfxCardStatus` to force use discrete Card, but neither worked.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you nvidia-331 package installed? Try to set nomodeset in grub and install the driver (apt-get install nvidia-331).

Comment: yes, I install 331 and 304, but neither worked